# How to map a json response that has both dot in the field name and has a value sub element

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{"resolution": [
      {
      "resolution.resolution_id": {"val": "28"},
      "resolution.resolution_comment": {"val": "sdfsdfsdfsdfs"},      
      "resolution.resolved_by_user": {"val": "XXX"}

   },
      {
      "resolution.resolution_id": {"val": "28"},
      "resolution.resolution_comment": {"val": "sdfsdfsdfsdfs"},
      "resolution.resolved_by_user": {"val": "YYY"}
   }
]}
```

and a JQGrid defintion :

```
$(newTable).jqGrid({
            url:"someurl",
            mtype: 'GET',
            datatype: "json",
            height: 250,
            colNames:['id'],
            colModel:[
                {
                    name:'resolution.resolution_id',index:'resolution.resolution_id',sorttype:'string', width:200
                },

            ],
            rowNum: 10000,
            pager:'#pager',
            toppager: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortname: 'resolution_id',
            jsonReader:{repeatitems: false,root:'resolution'},
            multiselect: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: "Resolution"
          })
```

How can I set the JSON map so that it can read the resolution.resolution_id?

I have tried various combinations of jsonmap:resolution.resolution_id.val

Also tried

```
jsonmap:function(row){return row["val"]}
```

to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this colModel and the following jsonmap:

```
colModel:[
{
    name:'resolution.resolution_id',
    index:'resolution.resolution_id',
    jsonmap : function (a) { var v = a["resolution.resolution_id"]; return v.val; },
    sorttype:'string', 
    width:200
},
....
]
```

or simpy

```
jsonmap : function (a) { return a["resolution.resolution_id"].val; },
```